# vim find report AND store number of occurrences in buffer

Tags: regex, search, vim, count

i get this part: s/pattern//gn
using vim to report number of occurrences of "pattern".

but is there some way to store that reported number in a buffer for later use?

Comment: please  include sample code you used and explain the problem

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I guess what you meant "buffer" is "register/variable".

There are different ways to achieve that:

- external command is most direct way, IMO

  ```
  let a=system('grep -c "yourPattern" '.expand("%:p"))
  ```

  Thus, variable `a` contains the count. But you need have `grep` available, and the vim buffer should be a file.
- With `searchpos()` function and loop.
  From col1 line1, calling `searchpos()` function, accumulate the matches, till the end of the file/buffer. You need implement the loop.
- with redirect (`:redir`) to redirect the message to register, then do further processing. Thus you can have `x matches in y lines` message in a register and pick the `x` out later.

I would prefer the first way.

`:h item` will show you the help doc for the item (function usage/option/command etc), do this if you didn't understand some command/function.

But first you should do `:h window`, to know what is a buffer/window in vim.

Comment: thanks for the response. however, the details are quite beyond my level of expertise. please excuse my ignorance. vim reports the number of hits at the bottom of the screen. clearly, that number must be held in some location (register, memory?). is there no way to access that location in a rather straightforward fashion?

Comment: you are right, the number must be saved somewhere in vim's source code. from vim application, AFAIK, no, we cannot read the count number somewhere directly.

Comment: great. thanks. you did not take my comment amiss. perhaps i'll move over and knock together a C# to take care of the problem.